# how to integrate kcfinder in tinymce 4?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, kcfinder

Has anyone successfully integrated kcfinder to tinymce 4?

There's a solution in the link below but it does not contain all the source code needed.

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=30896

Comment: really I need to find this, please let me know too if you find it. thanks.

Comment: I've settled for this [link](http://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/direct-image-uploads-in-tinymce-4-42/). It get's the job done instead of a full feature file manager.

Answer (score 0):

you should copy kcfinder folder in your server and  just set config.php file 
set uploadURL and uploadDIR

```
 'uploadURL' => "http://localhost/smartytest/upload/",
 'uploadDir' => "k:\xampp\htdocs\smartytest\upload\",
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS:

```
tinyMCE.init({mode:"exact",
skin:"o2k7",           
mode: "exact",
width : "650",
height:"200",
paste_text_use_dialog : true,
skin_variant:"silver",
relative_urls : true,
convert_urls : false,
elements:"contents",
theme:"advanced",
content_css : "javascript/tinymce/custom_css.css",

plugins:"pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,safari,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect, cut,copy,paste,pastetext",

theme_advanced_buttons2:"link,unlink,image,cleanup,code,|,forecolor,backcolor, table,advhr,|,sub,sup,|,fullscreen,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,undo,redo",

// theme_advanced_buttons3:"table,advhr,|,sub,sup,|,fullscreen",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location :"top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align        :"left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location :"none",
theme_advanced_path                 : false,
paste_retain_style_properties   :"all",
theme_advanced_resizing         :false,
file_browser_callback:"openKCFinder"});

function openKCFinder(c,a,b,d){tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({file:"javascript/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce&type="+b+"&dir="+b+"/public",title:"KCFinder",width:700,height:500,resizable:"yes",inline:true,close_previous:"no",popup_css:false},{window:d,input:c});return false};
```